# UPDATE query on row which leaves original time intact MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have got a script under this link [Order list/ while loop php issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410443/order-list-while-loop-php-issue) which retrieves an order row of data from the following fields:

```
order_id | users_id | total | order_date(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) | shipped
```

I have since added a radio button in which the admin user can click to show if this item has been shipped. (It adds a 'YES' or 'NO' to the shipped field through a submit button) The SQL query is below:

```
UPDATE orders SET shipped='$shipped' WHERE order_id='$id'
```

The script works fine but it replaces the time that the order was originally made (under 'order_date') with the time that the shipping button has been submitted and I want to leave the original time intact.

Can I change the SQL query or do I have to use php to this? Please let me know if you need to see the full php code.

```
<?php # edit_user.php

$page_title = 'View Individual Order';
include ('includes/header_admin_user.html');

// If no dealer_code variable exists, redirect the user.
if (!isset($_SESSION['admin_int_id'])) {

   // Start defining the URL.
   $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
    . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
   // Check for a trailing slash.
   if ((substr($url, -1) == '/') OR (substr($url, -1) == '\\') ) {
        $url = substr ($url, 0, -1); // Chop off the slash.
   }
   // Add the page.
   $url .= '/login.php'; 

ob_end_clean(); // Delete the buffer.
header("Location: $url"); 
exit(); // Quit the script.
}

// Check for a valid user ID, through GET or POST.
if ( (isset($_GET['id'])) && (is_numeric($_GET['id'])) )
   { // Accessed through view_users.php   
    $id = $_GET['id'];

} elseif ( (isset($_POST['id'])) && (is_numeric($_POST['id'])) )
   { // Form has been submitted.   
    $id = $_POST['id'];
} else { // No valid ID, kill the script.
    echo '<h1 id="mainhead">Page Error</h1>
    <p class="error">This page has been accessed in error.</p><p><br /><br /></p>';
    include ('./includes/header.html'); 
    exit();
}

?>

<h1>Order Details</h1>

<?php

require_once ('mydatabase.php'); // Connect to the db.

$shipped = $_POST["shipped"];

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

          // Make the query.
          $query = "UPDATE orders SET shipped='$shipped' WHERE order_id=$id";   
          $result = @mysql_query ($query); // Run the query.
          if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) { // If it ran OK.

          // Print a message.
          echo '<p style="color:#5a8e22;"><strong>The order has been sent.</strong></p>
          <br />';

          } else { // If it did not run OK.
            echo '<p style="color:#be0f34; font-size:120%;"><strong>Error</strong></p>
            <p style="color:#be0f34;">This update request could not be made for one of the following reasons:<br>
            <br>
            <a href="view-all-orders-test.php"><< Go back to order list</a>';   
           echo '<p>' . mysql_error() . '<br /><br />
            Query: ' . $query . '</p>
            </p>
            <br class="clearboth" />
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
            </div>'
            ; // Debugging message.   
          include ('./includes/footer_admin_user.html'); 
          exit();
          ; // Public message.

          }

} // End of submit conditional.


// Retrieve the user's, order and product information.
$query = "SELECT us.users_id, us.users_sales_guild_id, us.users_first_name, us.users_surname, us.users_dealer_name, us.users_type, 
         us.users_address_street, us.users_address_suburb, us.users_address_state, us.users_address_postcode, 
         us.users_address_phone, us.registration_date, 
         ord.order_id, ord.users_id, ord.total, ord.order_date,  
         oc.oc_id, oc.order_id, oc.products_id, oc.quantity, oc.price,
         prd.products_id, prd.products_name, prd.price      
         FROM users AS us, orders AS ord, order_contents AS oc, products AS prd  
         WHERE ord.order_id=$id
         AND us.users_id = ord.users_id
         AND ord.order_id = oc.order_id
         AND oc.products_id = prd.products_id    
         ";

$result = mysql_query ($query) or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result)) { // Valid user ID, show the form.

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);

   echo '<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr valign="top">
        <td width="65%"><p><strong>Deliver to:</strong><br />
        ' . $row[2] . ' ' . $row[3] . ' <br />
        ' . $row[5] . ', ' . $row[1] . ' <br />
        </p>

        <p><strong>Dealership:</strong><br />
        ' . $row[4] . ' <br />
        ' . $row[6] . ' <br />
        ' . $row[7] . ', ' . $row[8] . ', ' . $row[9] . ' <br />
        </p>

        </td>
        <td width="35%">
        <p><strong>Order Total:</strong><br />
        ' . $row[14] . ' pts <br />
        </p>
        <p><strong>Date:</strong><br />
        ' . $row[11] . ' <br />
        </p>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <form method="post" action="view-ind-order-test.php">
        Has this order been shipped?<br />
        Yes:<input type="radio" value="YES" name="shipped">  No:<input type="radio" value="NO" name="shipped"><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $id . '" />
        </form><br />

        <p></p> 

        <table border="0" width="400" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">
        <tr class="top">
        <td align="left" ><b>Product</b></td>
        <td align="center"><b>Qty</b></td>
        <td align="center"><b>Price</b></td>

        </tr>';

    $bg = '#dddddd'; // Set the background color.

    do { // DO WHILE loop start

    $bg = ($bg=='#eaeced' ? '#dddddd' : '#eaeced');

    echo    '<tr bgcolor="' . $bg . '">';

    echo    '<td align="left">' . $row[22] . '</td>
            <td align="center">' . $row[19] . '</td>
            <td align="center">' . $row[20] . '</td>
            </tr>';

            } while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM));// end of WHILE loop

        echo '</table>
            <br><br>
            <p><a href="view-all-orders-test.php"> << Back to Orders</a></p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            ';

} else { // Not a valid user ID.
    echo '<h1 id="mainhead">Page Error</h1>
    <p class="error">This page has been accessed in error.</p><p><br /><br /></p>';   
}

mysql_close(); // Close the database connection.


?>

<p>footer</p>

<?php
include ('./includes/footer_admin_user.html'); // Include the HTML footer.
?>
```

Comment: Add your code please so we can help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@gview is right that you should alter your table and make it DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.  If you cannot alter the table, you can change your update query to set order_date = order_date, which will prevent it from being updated:

```
UPDATE orders SET shipped='$shipped', order_date = order_date WHERE order_id='$id'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @nathan, this worked!
PS: I already had the "DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP" set in the table

Comment: @AdamMC, there is no need to update the order_date if you indeed have that set for the order_date column.  It is not a table setting, it is a column setting and needs to be set for the order_date column.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known issue with mysql timestamps.  You can read about the ins and outs of timestamps [Here](http://www.gizmola.com/blog/archives/93-Too-much-information-about-the-MySQL-TIMESTAMP.html)

The default behavior of the timestamp is to update on insert AND update.  You can change this by altering the table and adding a default to the timestamp definition:

```
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd make another field in the DB called "order_time" or something like that.  It can be good to know both the original date and the updated date.  timestamp will update every time some content is changed unless you modify the settings.

Use PHP's date() function as a variable for the order_time column and give it the exact time layout you want.

Comment: There is no need for that -- mysql has the built in NOW() that can always be passed as a constant.  However, the question posed was asking how to stop the original timestamp from changing, not about how to add a changed column.